# Cannot convert value of type '(NSData?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?

Tags: php, mysql, swift4

Hi all I am trying my hands on Swift and I am trying to post users registration data. I know how to do it firebase but my main project is in php mysql so I want to connect it with swift

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {

        //check textfield data
        checkTextFields()

        //create user
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/helo/register.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //apending body to url
        let body = "Fullname=\(name.text!.lowercased())&userName=\(userName.text!.lowercased())&emailAddress=\(emailAddress.text!.lowercased())&password=\(password.text!.lowercased())"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


        //lunching
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskWithRequest(request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

            if error == nil{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    do {
                        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as?
                        NSDictionary

                        guard let parseJSON = json else{
                            print("Error while parsing")
                            return
                        }
                        let id =  parseJSON["id"]

                        if id != nil {
                            print(parseJSON)
                        }

                    }catch{
                        print("Caugth an error: \(error)")
                    }

                })
            }else{
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        } )
    }
```

I am getting an error on the line where I have commented as as lunching which say

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NSData?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'
```

I am new to Swift any help is welcome thank you all. I am using Xcode 9

Comment: The docs show a signature of `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?)`.  Have you tried that instead of the NS stuff?

Comment: Just name it whatever you want and let it infer the types `data, response, error in`

Comment: @PhillipMills.. yes I have read it but still having same issue

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough reading, I just realised I was doing a very tedious and using orthodox method when things have improved. I removed the whole code and did everything with Alamofire. Its really easy and straight forward. I will post the code below to help others who encounter similar problems later on.

```
//Constant that holds the URL for our web servicer
        let URL_USER_REGISTER = "http://localhost:8888/members/register.php?"

        Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)

                //getting json value from the server
                if let result = response.result.value {

                    //converting it as NSDictionary
                    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                    //displaying the message in label
                    self.lableMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?
                }
        }
```

you have to first import Alamofire.